# is there a an excel formula that would allow me to calculate the total quantity of ingredients used?

Tags: excel, sumproduct

**attempting to re-phrase an earlier posting**

background: i work in F&B and I would like to calculate quantity of ingredients used for all products. a screen shot of the "cost file" calculating the quantity required of each ingredient is inserted below. each product has up to 10 ingredients, and each ingredient specification is located within it's respective "sub-table" (i.e., ingredient 1, ingredient 2, etc.).

[simplified cost file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTpfD.png)

i have not been successful with a sumproduct formula as I am not sure how to direct the formula to pull the quantity from the appropriate "sub-table". in other words, how would the formula know that in order to calculate the quantity of quantity of ingredient 4 that's used, you need to refer to sub-table 1 (ingredient 1) for product 1 and ingredient 2 for product 2?

[end goal with one standardized formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o2xD.png)

Comment: Then use index() with match() to pull those values.

Comment: @SolarMike am familiar with both sumproduct and index match function, and have also tried googling nesting index match function within sumproduct, but still cant figure out a way to calculate without having to do so one sub-table of the "cost file" at a time... could you pls give me another shove in the right direction